# Up-To-Bottom Box Layout in netbeans builder

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, boxlayout

I'm using netbeans GUI builder and I want to use Box layout that places the components up-to-bottom, the default for netbeans is left-to-right and I don't know how to change that !

Can anyone help how to get from here to there ?

Comment: `Can anyone help how to get from here to there ?` - don't use a GUI builder to create your forms. You are spending the time learning how to use the IDE not Swing. When you move to a different IDE the code will not be portable and you will need to learn another IDE. Instead create the forms manually and use the IDE to help with debugging and testing. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.

Comment: @camickr I see your point and I totally agree with you .. but I was in a hurry and (ironically) I wanted to finish some stuff quickly so I was hoping to get things done quickly with the IDE, but looks like it was a bad decision

Answer (score 3, accepted):

camickr is right, but if you want to stick with netbeans for whatever reason,

Select the form.
go to navigator and select the BoxLayout 
[image]

then in the properties window you can cycle between the Axis.

What you want is "Page Axis" or "Y Axis"

[image]